# Is there a tool that uses such a bowed blade?

Tags: tool-identification, blade

Or is the blade simply warped due to some unimaginable misuse?

It belonged to my great grandfather who died in 1968, so it should be a fairly modern tool.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This could be from a type of *side axe*, also referred to as a hewing axe.